# "That is the reason why..."

Tags: word-choice

To say `That's the reason why he came` would

> Das ist der Grund, warum er gekommen ist.
>
> Das ist der Grund, aus dem er gekommen ist.
>
> Das ist der Grund, weshalb er gekommen ist.
>
> Das ist der Grund, woraus er gekommen ist.

all be equally valid or are any of these wrong or carrying different connotations or something of the sort? What's the difference between these (assuming they're all valid)?

Comment: I am very far from the native level, but I never said any other as your first version. Grammatically can they be ok, but logically not. I hope a native will say some interesting about this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That is one of the most standard "mistakes" English speakers make. Valid are the following versions.

> Das ist der Grund dafür, dass...
>
> Das ist der Grund, aus dem (welchem)...

Those are correct because *aus* and *für* are the prepositions that are used with *Grund*

> aus einem Grund - for a reason
>
> der Grund für  - the reason for

Not really fit for print but not unheard of in spoken is this:

> Das ist der Grund, warum (weshalb,wieso)...

*Warum*
And this one doesn't work:

> Das ist der Grund, woraus...

It doesn't work because *Grund* is a defined thing and you can't use that with an open relative pointer like *woraus*

Compared to English, this way of phrasing ("That is the reason...") is somewhat rare. Maybe because it is a bit lengthy in German. In a lot of situations, especially if the sentences are short, people would use one of the following

> Deshalb (darum, deswegen)... that's why/therefore
>
> Von daher... "coming from there" (colloquial but super common and spreading)
>
> Aus diesem Grund... for that reason

Comment: There is also the plain “daher” meaning “deshalb”, which is not colloquial.