# "Dafür" vs. "dazu" (oder "darum"?)

Tags: word-usage, preposition

> Wir brauchen den Wagen, um in Urlaub zu fahren.

Wie kann man den Satzteil "um in Urlaub zu fahren" umschreiben?

> 1. Dafür brauchen wir den Wagen.
> 2. Dazu brauchen wir den Wagen.

Und weil er mit "um ..." beginnt, warum nicht, wenn nicht,

> 3. Darum (d. h., um zu fahren) brauchen wir den Wagen

?

Comment: Possible dupe of http://german.stackexchange.com/q/8759/3407

Comment: Doesn't look like the same question to me.

Comment: Die Umschreibung bezieht sich auf den Grund für etwas. Die Frage ist nicht diesselbe bzw. wurde nicht auf diesselbe Weise gestellt, fragt jedoch nach der gleichen Sache.

Comment: Es scheint mir, dass sich die Umschreibung hier auf einen Zweck oder ein Ziel bezieht, nicht auf einen Grund.

Comment: Alle drei Varianten sind möglich. Dazu/dafür entspricht: für diesen Zweck. Darum entspricht: aus diesem Grund.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kausalität war schon immer etwas schwammig, schon Aristoteles unterscheidet [vier Arten](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kausalit%C3%A4t#Aristoteles). "Darum" ist rein kausal (Grund), "dazu" und "dafür" sind final (Zweck), "Um ... zu" ist eher final, man kann es aber auch kausal verstehen.

Du kannst den Satz also umschreiben, wie du willst, je nachdem, welcher Aspekt gemeint ist (oder hervorgehoben werden soll).