# Zeit haben/nehmen zu oder für?

Tags: preposition, grammaticality

So I am having some problems trying to understand when to use `für` and `zu` while talking about `having time`

I have checked in https://www.linguee.de but I see lot of different sentences.

So far, correct me in case I am wrong:

- I have no time for something

  > Ich habe keine Zeit für etwas
  >   Ich habe keine Zeit dafür
- I have no time to do something

  > Ich habe keine Zeit, etwas zu machen
  >   Ich habe keine Zeit dazu
- I take some time for something/to do something

  > Ich nehme mir Zeit für etwas
  >   Ich nehme mir Zeit etwas zu machen

I am living in Germany so I asked a couple of germans how they use it and all of them said, they "never" use *»Ich habe keine Zeit dazu«* and always use *»dafür«*.

Could anyone explain me this scenarios?

Comment: Related: ["Dafür vs. dazu"](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/18830/daf%c3%bcr-vs-dazu-oder-darum)

Comment: Using stubs like *etwas, jemand* (something, someone) ist not good. Use concrete words, that you would use in normal speech too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As rule of thumb you can say: You use `zu` if a (unconjugated) verb is following and you use `für` if a substantive is following.

In the context of having time you are right: Using `dafür` is common (and sounds "good") while `dazu` is not common (but unfortunately i can not explain why.)