# „Das ist der Grund, warum/weshalb …“

Tags: grammar, style, conjunction, subordinate-clause, interrogative

Ich habe in einem [ähnlichen Beitrag](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/8759/that-is-the-reason-why) gesehen, dass „der Grund, warum/weshalb“ falsch sei. Allerdings habe ich als Muttersprachler mein ganzen Leben lang vorwiegend *warum* verwendet und auch fast ausschließlich gehört. Auch in Online-Lexika ist „der Grund warum/weshalb“ aufgeführt und nicht als umgangssprachlich gekennzeichnet.

Ist „der Grund dafür, dass …“ wirklich die einzige, “richtige” Möglichkeit? 
Und ist von den beiden von mir genannten wirklich im Schriftlichen abzuraten?

Comment: Im Schriftlichen ist manchmal so einiges abzuraten, aber nicht, weil es falsch ist, sondern weil es zu informell/umgangssprachlich ist. Wie das in dem konkreten Beispiel ist, weiß ich nicht, aber "falsch" ist es definitiv nicht.

Answer (score 7):

Ich bezweifle, dass die Antwort zu
["That is the reason why..."](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/8759/that-is-the-reason-why)
vollständig richtig ist. (Dort steht, *...der Grund warum/weshalb...* wäre "Not ready for print" [allerdings ohne weitere Begründung])

Wenn ich bei Google Books nach solchen Wendungen suche, finde ich massenhaft Literatur (auch zur/aus der Germanistik, und auch von an sich über jeden Zweifel erhabenen Autoren), die diese Formulierungen enthalten. Nur ein Beispiel: "Duden - Richtiges und gutes Deutsch, Eintrag zu *dreißig*":

> Der Grund, warum man dreißig mit ß, die anderen Zehner aber mit z schreibt...

Meinem eigenen Sprachgefühl nach ist *...der Grund warum/weshalb...* ebenfalls nicht falscher oder richtiger als das in der verlinkten Antwort präferierte *...der Grund dafür, dass...* oder *...der Grund, aus dem...*

Answer (score 4):

Im [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/warum) steht:

> *Beispiel*
> der Grund, warum er es getan hat, ist uns allen unbekannt

So falsch/unüblich kann es also nicht sein.